# How to verify if an rpm was installed from scratch or upgraded?

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

Today, we installed the following rpm's via yum on redhat version 5

```
# rpm -qa --last | head -10
  kernel-headers-2.6.18-408.el5                 Wed May 18 13:33:59 2016
  bind-utils-9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.6               Wed May 18 13:33:59 2016
  redhat-release-5Server-5.11.0.2               Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  nss-3.19.1-4.el5_11                           Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  nspr-4.10.8-2.el5_11                          Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  bind-libs-9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.6                Wed May 18 13:33:58 2016
  kernel-2.6.18-409.el5                         Wed May 18 04:13:58 2016
```

How can I tell if these RPMs were installed from scratch or just upgraded?

I try by **rpm -qi**

but from **rpm -qi** , we not get the info if rpm was installed from scratch or upgraded.

Secondly,  if an rpm was upgraded then how can I downgrade it to the previous version?

```
 more /var/log/yum.log
 Mar 22 11:06:19 Installed: yum-security-1.1.16-21.el5.noarch
 May 16 12:47:32 Installed: yum-utils-1.1.16-21.el5.noarch
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

Look at the yum log in /var/log/yum.log

2.

```
yum downgrade package1 [package2] [...]
```

For details look at the yum manpage

Comment: please see the yum.log I see only two lines?

Comment: Because you likely installed them with rpm command. Only yum put entries in log. -- Unless you are using System Management tools like RH Satellite, Spacewalk or similar there is not way to retrieve this informartion.

Comment: The question started with "Today, we installed the following rpm's via yum". If the packages are not installed via yum there can't be anything in yum.log. In this case you can look at /var/log/rpmpkgs which is a list of installed packages. if you compare it to /var/log/rpmpkgs.1 or /var/log/rpmpkgs.2 you should get what was intalled fresh in the last 2 weeks.